# Iterate over two arrays and make new array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
let names1 = ["om","karan","ranjett","rocky"] <br>
let names2 = ["vaibhu","Shrushti","rekha","kunal"]
```

How do you iterate over both arrays and makes a new object. Get one element from names1 also from names2 and one random number and push these into an object

eg:-

obj  = {

{

n1:"om"
n2: "vaibhu"
randomnumber:12
},

//remaining array

}

Comment: *"I want a code"*, this isn;t a free coding service. Please see [ask]. Show us your attempt

Comment: I believe you should consider the structure of your data. Iterating over 2 arrays considering they have the same length, would be risky.

Answer (score 1):

Just map over it?

```
let names1 = ["om","karan","ranjett","rocky"]
let names2 = ["vaibhu","Shrushti","rekha","kunal"]

const combined = names1.map((item, index) => ({
  n1: item,
  n2: names2[index],
  randomnumber: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)
}));

console.log(combined);

/*
[
  { n1: 'om', n2: 'vaibhu', randomnumber: 49 },
  { n1: 'karan', n2: 'Shrushti', randomnumber: 87 },
  { n1: 'ranjett', n2: 'rekha', randomnumber: 1 },
  { n1: 'rocky', n2: 'kunal', randomnumber: 74 }
]
*/
```